# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem class adds unwanted html span tags to email body

Tags: c#, mailitem

I have C# code that uses the  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem class to generate emails.  The code includes the following:

```
string body = "<p>For your information, the individuals below were recently reassigned:</p><ul>";
foreach (string n in reassigned)
    body += "<li>" + n + "</li>";
body += "</ul>";
```

When the above body string is assigned to the MailItem body property and then transmitted, a span tag is added inside the p tag: `<span style='color:white'>` which renders the text invisible.  How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't think it'll be added automatically by the library. You have to check your code to see where it's being added !

Comment: Is the `<span style='color:white'>` in the `n` string of the `reassigned` collection?  Where does the `<span>` occur in the output relative to the markup you provided?

Comment: The span tag is not added in code.  The tag is inserted immediately inside the p tag and nowhere else.  The unordered list (ul) built from the reassigned collection is left as coded.  No additional mark-up is added.